# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate unit test spring [Java]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

**Unit Testing with Spring framework - Java**

I got the below error when I run the spring unit test with a java context

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
```

My **pom.xml** have these dependencies but still faced this issue when i run my test case

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My current version of spring and java

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
```

I just change my **pom.xml**, remove the version then run, it worked perfectly

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 2.7 which is build with Spring 5.3. Spring 6 is for Spring Boot 3 (and is totally different). As you are using Spring Boot, use `spring-boot-starter-test` and remove the other test dependencies (junit, spring-test and mockito) those will be included in the proper compatible versions.

Comment: thanks, M. Deiunm yes, spring framework 6 and spring boot 3 are totally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code. I just change my **pom.xml**, remove the version from *org.springframework* then run, it worked perfectly

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Removing unwanted dependencies from the maven build resolved the issue.

**Yahoo!! Great**

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using `spring-test 6.0.4`. However, when I changed to using version `5.3.24` it started working.